# Angular app often takes too long when loading a path with a resolver using ssr

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs, server-side-rendering, angularfire

I am having some issues serving my app using ssr. It works fine when it loads normally using `ng s --o`. But when I serve it with  `npm run dev:ssr` and load the path it sometimes takes extremely long to serve while using the resolver below. Enough to timeout when deployed (>60s). I am using node 10.

**solution.resolver.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {
  Resolve,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot
} from '@angular/router';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap, reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Solution } from './Solution.type';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SolutionResolver implements Resolve<Solution[]> {
  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage
  ) {}
  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): Observable<any> { // Solution[]
    return this.firestore.collection('solutions').get() // Observable<doc>
    .pipe(
      map( snapshot => snapshot.docs.map( doc => doc.data() ) as Solution[]), // Observable<Solution[]>
      mergeMap( solutions => from(solutions) ), // stream of Observable<Solution>
      mergeMap( solution => {
        return this.storage.ref( solution.image ).getDownloadURL()
        .pipe( map( url => ({...solution, image: url}) ))
      }), // stream of <Observable<Solution>
      reduce( (acc: Solution[], value ) => {acc.push(value); return acc; }, []) // <Observable<Solution[]>
    )
  }
}
```

The issue may be related to `this.storage.ref( solution.image ).getDownloadURL()`. There are no error messages in the console. To make it even worse sometimes it does work as expected.

I previously had the same issue using the `getDownloadURL` pipe from `angularfire`: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#downloading-files

Any idea what is going wrong?

update: It's probably related to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2725

Comment: Did you add `console.time` instructions to check wether this was really the cause of the issue?

Comment: @David Logging just before `this.storage.ref( solution.image ).getDownloadURL()` actually works as expected. But the end result is not always served timely to my browser. Without fetching the `this.storage.ref( solution.image ).getDownloadURL()`this doesn't occur however.